# Can someone explain this regex

Tags: regex

I know this is a pretty basic regex, could someone explain what it is doing please?

```
^[^@]+@[-a-z0-9.]+$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

^ - match start of string

[^@]+ - match one or more characters that aren't an @

@ - match an @

[-a-z0-9.]+ - match one or more characters from the set '-', lower case 'a'-'z', the digits '0'-'9', '.'

$ - match end of string

So, match any string that consists of some characters that aren't '@', followed by '@', followed by some number of lower case letters / digits / dashes / full stops.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's trying to match an email address (not very well)

Example matches:

- `abc@example.com`
- `podcast@nospam.com`
- `hello(world)@9`
- `a[]&^&£^$^&£@.`

Answer (score 2):

It says "match one or more **non-@ character** followed by an **@**, followed by **one or more alphanumeric characters, a - or a .**" The **^** at the beginning and the **$** at the end signify this pattern must also be against the beginning and end of the entire string (^ means "beginning of string" and $ means "end of string").

Comment: The [^@]+ matches one OR MORE non-@ characters.

Answer (score 1):

Matches a string that doesn't start with at least 1 `@` character, followed by matching a `@`, then a `-`, `.` or any alphanumeric characters at least once.

I'm guessing it's a very loose email validator.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Rex's answer, it looks like a naive email validation regex.